# substitution and regex perl

Tags: regex, perl, string-substitution

Hello I am an amateur to perl and regex

I want to ask the following:

Is it possible to make one substitution argument for the following code:

```
($inputwoord =~s /[aa|uu|ee|oo]/[a|u|e|o]/) {}
```

I basically need to change all dipthongs, so only 1 vowel remains.

However Perl doesn't seem to understand that he must change aa => a 
oo => o etc ..

He crashes.

Is there a way to correlate the diphtong with the vowel in the same substitution? 
I don't want to make 4 different substitutions of it...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`[...]` defines a character class. `[aa]` is therefore equivalent to `[a]`.

If you want to search for repeated vowels, you can remember the vowel by a capturing parentheses:

```
/([aueo])\1/
```

This matches any character of the class, followed by the same character. To replace it with only one occurrence, use the capturing group again:

```
s/([aueo])\1/$1/g
```

So, to change the value of the variable $inputwoord:

```
$inputwoord =~ s/([aueo])\1/$1/g
```

BTW, instead of saying *He crashes*, it's more useful to show the actual error you get. You didn't show enough code for us to be able to guess why Perl crashed.